# c# transform line equation to change reference origin and angle

Tags: c#, geometry

Suppose I have the following situation.
I have a straight line equation in the form ***y=mx+q*** referred to the ***xOy*** plain.
I have the need to translate the line equation into the ***x'O'y'*** plain.
How would you procede in an efficient manner?

I should add that I know the coordinates and rotation of the two origins referred to a perfectly straight reference plain that can be seen as the paper on which the origins are drawn.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refer to wikipedia : [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#:~:text=If%20the%20curve%20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#:%7E:text=If%20the%20curve%20)

For just a rotation of coordinate systems: you can get the corpondances:

[image]

[image]

That's equivalent to :

[image]

[image]

in your case you can add the translation between the 2 coordinate systems, so you would have:

x' = x.cos(Th) + y.sin(Th) + tx

y' = -x.sin(Th) + y.cos(Th) + ty

with Th = Theta angle and T = (tx, ty) translation vector between both coordinate systems.

Once you have that you can simply replace x and y and simplify in the equation y=mx+q as you know:

y = mx + q

y' = m2 x' + q2

x' = x.cos(Th) + y.sin(Th) + tx

y' = -x.sin(Th) + y.cos(Th) + ty

(your goal is to find m2 and q2 knowing Theta and T)

**Note**: I think in 2D it is better to use the general equation of straight lines which is `ax + by +c = 0` instead of the one you use `y = mx +q`. This is because vertical lines, whose equation are of the form "x = q" can't be written with the form `y = mx +q`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the ***laser*** is my reference point for the line I did as follows:

```
private Model RotoTranslate(Model line, LaserContainer laser)
{
    Model transformModel = new Model();
    float cosA = (float)Math.Cos((laser.Rotation * Math.PI) / 180.0f);
    float sinA = (float)Math.Sin((laser.Rotation * Math.PI) / 180.0f);

    if (line.XModel)
    {
        transformModel.XModel = true;
        transformModel.M = ((line.M * cosA) - sinA) / ((line.M * sinA) + cosA);
        transformModel.Q = (line.Q + (laser.PositionGraph.Y * ((line.M * sinA) + cosA)) -
                           (laser.PositionGraph.X * ((line.M * cosA) - sinA))) / ((line.M * sinA) + cosA);
    }
    else
    {
        transformModel.XModel = false;
        transformModel.M = ((line.M * cosA) + sinA) / (-(line.M * sinA) + cosA);
        transformModel.Q = (line.Q + (laser.PositionGraph.X * (-(line.M * sinA) + cosA)) -
                           (laser.PositionGraph.Y * ((line.M * cosA) + sinA))) / (-(line.M * sinA) + cosA);
    }

    return transformModel;
}
```

I have to test now and see if there are exceptions I didn't account for...
The definition of XModel essentially refers to the way the line equation is expressed.
If the model has:

```
 XModel = true;
```

then the equation is in the form ***y=mx+q***, otherwise it's in the form ***x=my+q***;